# Testing for a "if not defined" boolean

Tags: conditionals

How can I test for a not defined boolean?

I want to have

```
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\providebool{is_single_book}
\booltrue{is_single_book}
```

in my `main.tex` and in each of the chapter TeX files.

```
if not defined is_single_book
  \externaldocument{volume1}[http://mybook.com/volume1.pdf]
fi
```

So when I compile the entire book, `\externaldocument{volume1}[http://mybook.com/volume1.pdf]` isn't executed.

It doesn't have to be a boolean if something else is simpler or doesn't require an extra package.

Comment: Why do you want "is not defined" rather than "true" and "false"? Does a package specify that boolean?

Comment: So you essentially want a three-way switch: boolean undefined, boolean true and boolean false? Or can you simplify this to a simple two-valued logic with a true and false boolean? Since you use `etoolbox` commands you can use `\ifcsundef{ifis_single_book}{<undef>}{<def>}` to check if the boolean `is_single_book` is undefined. Note that `\providebool` makes sure the boolean is defined, so `\ifcsundef{ifis_single_book}` will execute the false branch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While you could check if a bool is defined by using `\ifcsundef{if...}` (see comment from moewe), it looks as if you actually want a boolean which is always false if you are in a chapter tex file.

This can be archived by using `\providebool`, which defines the bool as false, iff is is not defined already:

Use

```
\newbool{is_single_book}
\booltrue{is_single_book}
```

in your main file and

```
\providebool{is_single_book}
\ifbool{is_single_book}{}{%
  \externaldocument{volume1}[http://mybook.com/volume1.pdf]%
}
```

in your chapter files.

Even better would be to use toggles. They are almost the same but avoid name clashes and provide slightly better performance:

To use them, insert

```
\newtoggle{is_single_book}
\toggletrue{is_single_book}
```

in your main file and

```
\providetoggle{is_single_book}
\iftoggle{is_single_book}{}{%
  \externaldocument{volume1}[http://mybook.com/volume1.pdf]%
}
```

in the chapters.

Comment: Something seams to be wrong for the chapters part. `\externaldocument{volume1}[http://mybook.com/volume1.pdf]` isn't being executed. Is `is_single_book` true or fasle right after `\providetoggle{is_single_book}`?

Comment: `\externaldocument{volume1}[http://mybook.com/volume1.pdf]` should be executed if `is_single_book` is `false` or `undefined`.

Answer (score 9):

`\providebool` and `\booltrue` makes me think you are using [`etoolbox`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox).

`etoolbox` booleans are just a thin wrapper around TeX's `\newif`.

That means that `\newbool{<name>}` defines `\if<name>`, so you can check if a boolean is defined by checking if `\if<name>` is defined.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand*{\ifboolundef}[1]{\ifcsundef{if#1}}

\newcommand*{\sabooleantest}[1]{%
  bool \ttfamily{#1} is
  \ifboolundef{#1}
    {undefined}
    {\ifbool{#1}
       {true}
       {false}}}

\begin{document}
\sabooleantest{flobbel}

\newbool{globbel}
\boolfalse{globbel}
\sabooleantest{globbel}

\newbool{hobbel}
\booltrue{hobbel}
\sabooleantest{hobbel}
\end{document}
```

> bool `flobbel` is undefined
>
> bool `globbel` is false
>
> bool `hobbel` is true

The question is whether you really need something that comes down to a three-valued logic. Is a two-valued boolean not enough?

If you want to avoid problems in case the boolean is undefined, you could just check if a macro is undefined or defined. This also has two states, but unlike with booleans there are no errors if the thing is not defined.

```
\newcommand*{\mybool}{}
\ifundef{\mybool}
  {not defined}
  {defined}
```

You could also define 'permissive toggles' that are false if they don't exist

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand*{\permissivetoggletrue}[1]{\csletcs{sa@ptogl@#1}{@empty}}
\newcommand*{\permissivetogglefalse}[1]{\csundef{sa@ptogl@#1}}
\newcommand*{\ifpermissivetoggle}[1]{\ifcsdef{sa@ptogl@#1}}

\begin{document}
flobbel
\ifpermissivetoggle{flobbel}
  {true}
  {false}

\permissivetoggletrue{globbel}
globbel
\ifpermissivetoggle{globbel}
  {true}
  {false}
\end{document}
```

This can also be done without `etoolbox` if you like those sort of things

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\permissivetoggletrue}[1]{%
  \expandafter\let\csname sa@ptogl@#1\endcsname\@empty}
\newcommand*{\permissivetogglefalse}[1]{%
  \expandafter\let\csname sa@ptogl@#1\endcsname\@sa@undef}% this assumes \@sa@undef is undefined
\newcommand*{\ifpermissivetoggle}[1]{%
  \ifcsname sa@ptogl@#1\endcsname
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I were only using `etoolbox` for this one thing, so if this package can be avoided, then it would be much appreciated.

Comment: @SandraSchlichting Theoretically especially in my last two examples we could do away with `etoolbox`, but I would end up essentially copying (a bit of) code from that package, so why not load it?

Comment: I see. Good point.

Answer (score 2):

> It doesn't have to be a boolean, if something else is simpler or doesn't require an extra package.

I think `\ifdefined` and `\def` provide what you're looking for. You don't need an extra package or any definition.

In your main document, write

```
\def\isSingleBook{}
```

or, alternatively, `\newcommand{\isSingleBook}{}` or `\providecommand{\isSingleBook}{}`.

Then you can check with:

```
\ifdefined\isSingleBook
  %% you're in the book
\else
  %% you're not in the book
\fi
```